# Setting up nginx to redirect to the root of the domain on directory browsing

Tags: nginx, configuration, root

Can we set up nginx to redirect to the root of our domain if the user attempts to browse any directories that do not have index.php or index.html?  I have this in my conf file, but now it seems to be blocking valid page access:

```
location /* {
    deny all;
    return 301 /;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default nginx behavior is to throw 403 Forbidden on such directories unless you have `autoindex on;` directive in your config or change default behavior with custom `try_files` directive. The simplest thing you can do is to override this error with redirection to your site root URI:

```
error_page 403 =301 /;
```